# Tornado: mime-type of the stream_request_body output

Tags: python-3.x, mime-types, tornado, content-type

I'm using `tornado.web.stream_request_body` (tornado v4.0.1) to save post data but it seems like mime-type of the saved files remain as `application/octet-stream`.

i need to know mime-type of the uploaded file and here is my code snippet;

```
@stream_request_body
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        pass

    def prepare(self):
        self.temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

    def data_received(self, chunk):
        self.temp_file.write(chunk)
```

extra information;
files are saved properly using `curl` with `--data-binary` parameter;

`curl -v -XPOST --data-binary @example.pdf localhost:8888/`

but browser uploads with `multipart/form-data` or curl with parameter `-d` does not work.
When i look into saved file with text editor, i see http post parameters at the first lines;

```
-----------------------------192365691191582744435855330
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="example.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mpeg

...
unreadable binary data
```

any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stream_request_body mode you get the raw body as uploaded by the client, without the processing that creates self.request.arguments or self.request.files.  This is a multipart/form-data wrapper (not the http headers, although they do look similar); you'll need to parse this to get the filename and the embedded data.  I think the mime-related tools in the standard library's email package are probably the best way to parse this once you've gotten it saved to a file.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The best bet is email.contentmanager. https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.contentmanager.html However it also loads mime messages into memory. I wonder if anybody has created a Python function for this already, that can extract files from raw post data, without using too much memory.

Comment: Hmmm maybe using the headersonly parameter, you will be able to process the headers only, and get the content-type. But not the data...

Answer (score 8):

UPDATE: I have created a package for Python3 and Tornado 4.0+ that can be installed with PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tornadostreamform

I know that the previous answer was already accepted, but I have had the same problem and I can provide a complete module - let's call it post_streamer - for Python 3 that will parse any stream into parts for any request, without using too much memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Post data streamer for tornadoweb 4.0"""
import os
import re
import random
import tempfile

class SizeLimitError(Exception):
    pass

class PostDataStreamer:
    """Parse a stream of multpart/form-data.

    Useful for request handlers decorated with tornado.web.stream_request_body"""
    SEP = b"\r\n"
    LSEP = len(SEP)
    PAT_HEADERVALUE = re.compile(r"""([^:]+):\s+([^\s;]+)(.*)""")
    PAT_HEADERPARAMS = re.compile(r""";\s*([^=]+)=\"(.*?)\"(.*)""")

    # Encoding for the header values. Only header name and parameters
    # will be decoded. Streamed data will remain binary.
    # This is required because multipart/form-data headers cannot
    # be parsed without a valid encoding.
    header_encoding = "UTF-8"

    def __init__(self, total, tmpdir=None):
        self.buf = b""
        self.dlen = None
        self.delimiter = None
        self.in_data = False
        self.headers = []
        self.parts = []
        self.total = total
        self.received = 0
        self.tmpdir = tmpdir

    def _get_raw_header(self,data):
        idx = data.find(self.SEP)
        if idx>=0:
            return (data[:idx], data[idx+self.LSEP:])
        else:
            return (None, data)

    def receive(self, chunk):
        self.received += len(chunk)
        self.on_progress()
        self.buf += chunk

        if not self.delimiter:
            self.delimiter, self.buf = self._get_raw_header(self.buf)
            if self.delimiter:
                self.delimiter+=self.SEP
                self.dlen = len(self.delimiter)
            elif len(self.buf)>1000:
                raise Exception("Cannot find multipart delimiter")
            else:
                return

        while True:
            if self.in_data:
                if (len(self.buf)>3*self.dlen):
                    idx = self.buf.find(self.SEP+self.delimiter)
                    if idx>=0:
                        self.feed_part(self.buf[:idx])
                        self.end_part()
                        self.buf = self.buf[idx+len(self.SEP+self.delimiter):]
                        self.in_data = False
                    else:
                        limit = len(self.buf)-2*self.dlen
                        self.feed_part(self.buf[:limit])
                        self.buf = self.buf[limit:]
                        return
                else:
                    return
            if not self.in_data:
                while True:
                    header, self.buf = self._get_raw_header(self.buf)
                    if header==b"":
                        assert(self.delimiter)
                        self.in_data = True
                        self.begin_part(self.headers)
                        self.headers = []
                        break
                    elif header:
                        self.headers.append(self.parse_header(header))
                    else:
                        # Header is None, not enough data yet
                        return

    def parse_header(self,header):
        header = header.decode(self.header_encoding)
        res = self.PAT_HEADERVALUE.match(header)
        if res:
            name,value,tail = res.groups()
            params = {}
            hdr = {"name":name,"value":value,"params":params}
            while True:
                res = self.PAT_HEADERPARAMS.match(tail)
                if not res:
                    break
                fname,fvalue,tail = res.groups()
                params[fname] = fvalue
            return hdr
        else:
            return {"value":header}

    def begin_part(self,headers):
        """Internal method called when a new part is started."""
        self.fout = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
            dir=self.tmpdir, delete=False)
        self.part = {
            "headers":headers,
            "size":0,
            "tmpfile":self.fout
        }
        self.parts.append(self.part)

    def feed_part(self,data):
        """Internal method called when content is added to the current part."""
        self.fout.write(data)
        self.part["size"] += len(data)

    def end_part(self):
        """Internal method called when receiving the current part has finished."""
        # Will not close the file here, so we will be able to read later.
        #self.fout.close()            
        #self.fout.flush() This is not needed because we update part["size"]
        pass

    def finish_receive(self):
        """Call this after the last receive() call.

        You MUST call this before using the parts."""
        if self.in_data:
            idx = self.buf.rfind(self.SEP+self.delimiter[:-2])
            if idx>0:
                self.feed_part(self.buf[:idx])
            self.end_part()

    def release_parts(self):
        """Call this to remove the temporary files."""
        for part in self.parts:
            part["tmpfile"].close()
            os.unlink(part["tmpfile"].name)

    def get_part_payload(self, part):
        """Return the contents of a part.

        Warning: do not use this for big files!"""
        fsource = part["tmpfile"]
        fsource.seek(0)
        return fsource.read()

    def get_part_ct_params(self, part):
        """Get content-disposition parameters.

        If there is no content-disposition header then it returns an
        empty list."""
        for header in part["headers"]:
            if header.get("name","").lower().strip()=="content-disposition":
                return header.get("params",[])
        return []

    def get_part_ct_param(self, part, pname, defval=None):
        """Get parameter for a part.

        @param part: The part
        @param pname: Name of the parameter, case insensitive
        @param defval: Value to return when not found.
        """
        ct_params = self.get_part_ct_params(part)
        for name in ct_params:
            if name.lower().strip()==pname:
                return ct_params[name]
        return defval

    def get_part_name(self, part):
        """Get name of a part.

        When not given, returns None."""
        return self.get_part_ct_param(part, "name", None)

    def get_parts_by_name(self, pname):
        """Get a parts by name.

        @param pname: Name of the part. This is case sensitive!

        Attention! A form may have posted multiple values for the same
        name. So the return value of this method is a list of parts!"""
        res = []
        for part in self.parts:
            name = self.get_part_name(part)
            if name==pname:
                res.append(part)
        return res

    def get_values(self, fnames, size_limit=10*1024):
        """Return a dictionary of values for the given field names.

        @param fnames: A list of field names.
        @param size_limit: Maximum size of the value of a single field.
            If a field's size exceeds this then SizeLimitError is raised.

        Warning: do not use this for big file values.
        Warning: a form may have posted multiple values for a field name.
            This method returns the first available value for that name.
            To get all values, use the get_parts_by_name method.
        Tip: use get_nonfile_names() to get a list of field names
            that are not originally files.
        """
        res = {}
        for fname in fnames:
            parts = self.get_parts_by_name(fname)
            if not parts:
                raise KeyError("No such field: %s"%fname)
            size = parts[0]["size"]
            if size>size_limit:
                raise SizeLimitError("Part size=%s > limit=%s"%(size, limit))
            res[fname] = self.get_part_payload(parts[0])
        return res

    def get_nonfile_names(self):
        """Get a list of part names are originally not files.

        It examines the filename attribute of the content-disposition header.
        Be aware that these fields still may be huge in size."""
        res = []
        for part in self.parts:
            filename = self.get_part_ct_param(part, "filename", None)
            if filename is None:
                name = self.get_part_name(part)
                if name:
                    res.append(name)
        return res

    def examine(self):
        """Debugging method for examining received data."""
        print("============= structure =============")
        for idx,part in enumerate(self.parts):
            print("PART #",idx)
            print("    HEADERS")
            for header in part["headers"]:
                print("        ",repr(header.get("name","")),"=",repr(header.get("value","")))
                params = header.get("params",None)
                if params:
                    for pname in params:
                        print("            ",repr(pname),"=",repr(params[pname]))
            print("    DATA")
            print("        SIZE", part["size"])
            print("        LOCATION",part["tmpfile"].name)
            if part["size"]<80:
                print("        PAYLOAD:",repr(self.get_part_payload(part)))
            else:
                print("        PAYLOAD:","<too long...>")
        print("========== non-file values ==========")
        print(self.get_values(self.get_nonfile_names()))


    def on_progress(self):
        """Override this function to handle progress of receiving data."""
        pass # Received <self.received> of <self.total>
```

It could be a bit more efficient, but it is portable and does not load anything big into memory. Here is how you can use it, tested with tornado web 4.0, (and firefox and pycurl as the client). Just start this server and point your browser to your localhost, port 8888

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application, url, stream_request_body
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from post_streamer import PostDataStreamer
import sys

class MyPostDataStreamer(PostDataStreamer):
    percent = 0

    def on_progress(self):
        """Override this function to handle progress of receiving data."""
        if self.total:
            new_percent = self.received*100//self.total
            if new_percent != self.percent:
                self.percent = new_percent
                print("progress",new_percent)

@stream_request_body 
class StreamHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('''<html><body>
<form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File #1: <input name="file1" type="file"><br>
File #2: <input name="file2" type="file"><br>
File #3: <input name="file3" type="file"><br>
Other field 1: <input name="other1" type="text"><br>
Other field 2: <input name="other2" type="text"><br>
Other field 3: <input name="other3" type="text"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body></html>''')

    def post(self):
        try:
            #self.fout.close()
            self.ps.finish_receive()
            # Use parts here!
            self.set_header("Content-Type","text/plain")
            oout = sys.stdout
            try:
                sys.stdout = self
                self.ps.examine()
            finally:
                sys.stdout = oout
        finally:
            # Don't forget to release temporary files.
            self.ps.release_parts()

    def prepare(self):
        # TODO: get content length here?
        try:
            total = int(self.request.headers.get("Content-Length","0"))
        except:
            total = 0
        self.ps = MyPostDataStreamer(total) #,tmpdir="/tmp"
        #self.fout = open("raw_received.dat","wb+")

    def data_received(self, chunk):
        #self.fout.write(chunk)
        self.ps.receive(chunk)

def main():
    application = Application([
        url(r"/", StreamHandler),
    ])
    max_buffer_size = 4 * 1024**3 # 4GB
    http_server = HTTPServer(
        application,
        max_buffer_size=max_buffer_size,
    )
    http_server.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.instance().start()

main()
```

After finish_receive() was called, you can access the Content-Type header using PostDataStreamer.params and PostDataStreamer.get_part_ct_param(part, "Content-Type")

UPDATE: the max_buffer_size should not be increased in general. The max_body_size should not be increased in general. They should be kept at low values. Only in the prepare() method of the handler that was decorated with stream_request_body, should we call self.request.connection.set_max_body_size() in order to set the maximum size that can be streamed. For details see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/izEXQd71rQk

This was an undocumented part of tornado. I'm preparing a module that can be used for handling file uploads out of the box. When ready, I'll put a link here.

Comment: Wow great work! Tested it and it works as intended! One improvement.. Tornado is limiting the body size by default to 100MB. You can use `self.request.connection.set_max_body_size(size)` in the initalization of the Request handler.

Comment: Agreed this does work after a bit of working out the parameters, good stuff.

Comment: Equanox: I'm updating this because - as it turned out - the max_body_size and also the max_buffer_size cannot be safely increased in the normal way.

Comment: I have abandoned this project a long time ago. Since then, another project was created for streaming multipart forms with tornado. I think it is easier to use than mine. I would only recommend tornadostreamform if you don't have a fixed number of form fields and names. The streaming-form-data module can only handle fields that are known in advance.