# Tornado server does not receive big files

Tags: rest, python-3.x, tornado

Hi I'm trying to realize a Tornado server with the goal to receive very big binary files (~1GB) into POST body. The following code works for small files, but does not answer if I try to send big files (~100MB).

```
class ReceiveLogs(tornado.web.RequestHandler):  
   def post(self):    
      file1 = self.request.body
      output_file = open('./output.zip', 'wb')
      output_file.write(file1)
      output_file.close()        
      self.finish("file is uploaded")
```

Do you know any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a real implementation as an answer but one or two remarks that hopefully point to the right direction.

First of all there is a 100MB Upload limit which can be increased setting the

```
self.request.connection.set_max_body_size(size)
```

in the initalization of the Request handler. ([taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529804/tornado-mime-type-of-the-stream-request-body-output))

The Problem is that tornado handles all file uploads in memory (and that HTTP is not a very reliable Protocol for handling large file uploads.)
This is quote from a member of the tornadoweb team from 2014 ([see github issue here](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/1026))

> ... You can adjust this limit with the max_buffer_size argument to the
>   HTTPServer constructor, although I don't think it would be a good idea
>   to set this larger than say 100MB.
>
> Tornado does not currently support very large file uploads. Better
>   support is coming (#1021) and the nginx upload module is a popular
>   workaround in the meantime. However, I would advise against doing 1GB+
>   uploads in a single HTTP POST in any case, because HTTP alone does not
>   have good support for resuming a partially-completed upload (in
>   addition to the aforementioned error problem). Consider a multi-step
>   upload process like Dropbox's chunked_upload and commit_chunked_upload
>   (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#chunked-upload)

As stated I would recommend to do one of the following:

- if NGNIX is possible to handle and route requests to tornado=> look
  at the NGNIX upload module ([see ngnix wiki here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/))
- If it must be a plain tornado solution use the
  tornado.web.stream_request_body which came with tornado 4. This
  streams the uploaded files to disk instead of trying to first get
  them all in mem. ([see tornado 4 release notes](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v4.0.0.html) and [this solution on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529804/tornado-mime-type-of-the-stream-request-body-output))